# How to pass a list as an Oracle query and return list items that satisfy a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table `backups` with a column `name` containing name+date of file backups.
Example:

```
ID   Name 
11   "ABC_20220601" 
22   "ABC_20220531" 
33   "XYZ_20220531" 
44   "LMN_20220530"
```

There's a SQL query that returns backup names that match a given string:

```
String sql = String.format("select name from backups where name like '%s'", fileName);
return jdbcConnection.executeQuery(sql);
```

> Example: if fileName = "ABC", query returns ["ABC_20220601"].

I need to modify this query such that the new parameter is a list of file names (`List<String> fileNames`) instead of the single `fileName`, and return those values from the *list* (instead of the `backups` table) that satisfy the `like` condition.

> Example: if fileNames contains ["ABC", "LMN", "PQR"], query should return ["ABC", "LMN"]
> and not ["ABC_20220601", "ABC_20220531", "LMN_20220530"]

What's the best way to write the new query? Please help.

Comment: use select regexp_substr(name,'[[:alpha:]]+').... rest of query

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build query from the list of strings as below:

```
select ID, CASE 
WHEN 
NAME LIKE ('%ABC%') THEN 'ABC'
WHEN 
NAME LIKE ('%XYZ%') THEN 'XYZ'
END AS name
from backups
```

See [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfe914cc06ec7141cb31c63fee92920a)

Comment: But in my case, I don't know what elements the list contains, so I can't directly use %ABC% or %XYZ% @Aleksandr Latman

Comment: How do you build the query? Is it all within Oracle? There is Dynamic SQL - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011 Something you can look at.